# While loop not stopping with given criteria

Tags: iphone, objective-c, while-loop

Im having a bit of a problem with this while loop. I keep getting a crash because it continues to execute the loop even when it has found the object and supposedly increased the int. 
Any ideas I have plenty of other loops set up in a similar way and they all work fine.

```
int possible = 0;

while (possible < [possibleAthetes count]) {
    if ([[[possibleAthetes objectAtIndex:possible]valueForKey:@"ID"]intValue] == [self.athleteID intValue]) {        
        [possibleAthetes removeObjectAtIndex:possible];
        possible = [possibleAthetes count] ;
    }
    possible ++;
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: No obvious reason for a crash. However assuming you only use `possible` to control the loop the more direct way to terminate it is to change `possible = [possibleAthetes];` to `break;` - `break` will terminate the enclosing loop.

Comment: Thanks for the posts, after moving on from this problem I have noticed that this loop isn't in fact the problem but for some reason Xcode was highlighting it after the crash.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing possible even when you remove an object.  Break out of the loop.

If you need to get rid of multiple athletes, leave out the break(No need to increment because of the removed object).

```
int possible = 0;

while (possible < [possibleAthetes count]) {

    BOOL criteriaMatch = ([[[possibleAthetes objectAtIndex:possible]valueForKey:@"ID"]intValue] == [self.athleteID intValue]);

    if  (criteriaMatch){        
        [possibleAthetes removeObjectAtIndex:possible];
        break;
    } else {
        possible++;
    }
}
```